# const void * object initialization issue C++

Tags: c++

I have a `class`called `Tracer` in C++. In my `Tracer.h` file I have:

```
class Tracer{

public:
    // not useful to the question.
private:
    Logger *m_logger;
    const char *m_who;
    const char *m_fileName;
    const void * m_theObject;
    int m_lineNum;
    int m_log_level;
}
```

And in `Tracer.cpp` I have:

```
Tracer::Tracer(
        Logger *logger,
        const void *theObject,
        const char *who,
        const char *file,
        int line,
        int log_level
        ) :
        m_logger(logger),
        m_who(who),
        m_fileName(file),
        m_lineNum(line),
        m_theObject(theObject),
        m_log_level(log_level)
{
  // more implementation which is not useful to the problem.
```

The problem is, when I initialize `m_theObject(theObject)`, I get the following **warning**:

```
/home/pribeiro/workspace/Tracer.h:80: warning:   'const void* Tracer::m_theObject'
/home/pribeiro/workspace/Tracer.cpp:27: warning:   when initialized here
```

`Tracer.h:80` is the declaration of `m_theObject` in the `Tracer.h` and `Tracer.cpp:27` is the `m_theObject(theObject` line.
In my compilation level, **warnings** are treated like **errors**. Why is the compiler complaining about the initiliazation of a `const void *` pointer?

Comment: Swap `m_lineNum(line)` and `m_theObject(theObject)` in the initializer list.

Answer (score 4):

That's not the whole warning.  It's actually warning that `m_lineNum` and `m_theObject` are being initialised in the wrong order (see [Member fields, order of construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308915/member-fields-order-of-construction)):

```
Tracer.h:80: warning:   'const void* Tracer::m_theObject' is initialized before 'int Tracer::m_lineNum'
Tracer.cpp:27: warning:   when initialized here
```

The fix is to swap the order of initialisation, or the order of definition:

```
Tracer::Tracer(
        Logger *logger,
        const void *theObject,
        const char *who,
        const char *file,
        int line,
        int log_level
        ) :
        m_logger(logger),
        m_who(who),
        m_fileName(file),
        m_theObject(theObject),    // here
        m_lineNum(line),           // and here
        m_log_level(log_level)
{
  // more implementation which is not useful to the problem.
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes compilers give a warning when members are initialised in the member initialisation list in a different order than they are declared in the header. I have seen g++ do this before. If you reorder your initialisation list so that it is in the same order as the members appear in your header file you should see this warning disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that, as per the C++ Standard, member variables are **always** (***ALWAYS***) initialized in the order of declaration, regardless of the order you give in the constructor.

The compiler nicely warns you about your misfit, because possibly you introduce unintended dependency chains.

---

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    int _1, _2, _3;

    Foo() : _3(_2+_1),  // Third initialization
            _2(_1+_1),  // Second initialization
            _1(1)       // First initialization
    {}
};

#include <iostream>
int main () {
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f._1 << f._2 << f._3 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
123
```

But the order of member initializers may let the maintainer think he could do better:

```
struct Foo {
    int _1, _2, _3;

    Foo() : _3(3),
            _2(_3-1),
            _1(_2-1)
    {}
};

#include <iostream>
int main () {
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f._1 << f._2 << f._3 << '\n';
}
```

One might again expect the output of `123` as it looks like `_3` is initiliazed first in that constructor. But that's not true:

```
./teh_program
13451434436167553
./teh_program
134514344118742913
./teh_program
13451434495068033
```

The results are totally unpredictable, multiple runs give different results without even recompiling. And the compiler is to prevent accidents like this.